# Which forces act on a motorcycle when braking mid-corner?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, everyday-life

Assuming a flat surface and steady rate of turn, a motorcycle rounds a corner at a constant speed and in a stable fashion -- that is, the bike is leaning into the corner. Part way through, it begins to brake.

- What are the major forces involved?
- Assuming no change of input via forces on the handlebars, does the bike begin to straighten or to lean over further?

I ride, but my bike is currently off the road for the winter so I can't take it out and try. My gut says the bike will "want to" straighten up in this scenario. But at the same time I know that when leaning over if I speed up quickly the bike will straighten up, and it seems counter-intuitive to me that both of those could be true. I expect that in practice I'm adding inputs without realizing it in either or both cases, and that's clouding my understanding.

- Does it make a difference whether the front or back brakes are being used?

Assume we're not braking hard enough to lock up either wheel.

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Not sure why I've picked up the "homework" tag and been downvoted here. This isn't homework. My bike is off the road for the winter (so I can't try it and see) and I had a discussion with a friend about this. I was convinced the bike would pick itself up if I brake in a corner, but he asked why and I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: The issue in my mind is that when leaned over if I *speed up* the bike picks itself up. It seems to me slowing down and speeding up should have opposite effects on the lean of the bike.

Comment: Added some of this to the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a nontrivial question. As a motorcyclist, I will try to explain it.

The major forces are the mass of the bike, the centrifugal force generated by the turn, and the friction force acting on the bike through the tire's contact patch with the pavement.

In a steady-state leaned turn, the force directed towards the center of the turn radius (which turns the bike) is provided by the horizontal component of the reaction force applied by the pavement to the tire's contact patch. The magnitude of the horizontal component necessary to execute the turn is determined by the bike's speed and the radius of the turn, which the rider produces and coordinates by control of the lean angle. More speed and a sharper turn require more lean angle.

Assume a left turn in what follows:

If the rider applies braking in the middle of a properly coordinated left turn as described above, the bike slows down and if the turn radius is maintained constant, less radially-directed force is required to turn the bike. This means the bike is over-leaned and will tend to roll left into the turn, increasing the lean angle.

To prevent the bike from laying down into a lowside crash, the rider has to steer left ("into" the turn) to move the tire's contact patch towards the left and reduce the length of the lever arm through which the bike's center of mass is trying to roll the bike over. This action decreases the turn radius, tightening the turn. Conclusion: applying the brakes once a coordinated turn has been established requires the rider to tighten the turn to prevent a lowside crash.

It makes a big difference whether the rider applies the front or the rear brake. There are second-order effects galore in this context but I will sketch out just the first-order effects which come into play when the bike's tires are operating near their adhesion limit i.e., when the bike is in danger of skidding.

If the rider applies the rear brake near the rear tire's adhesion limit, the rear tire may break loose and skid, causing the rear end of the bike to swing suddenly outwards. This establishes a counterclockwise rotation of the bike which rotates the skidding rear tire to the left and the friction force at the contact patch now has a force component which tends to suddenly roll the bike violently to the right. The rider is thrown off the bike and the bike is destroyed in a complicated rightwards end-over-end tumble. This is called a highside crash.

If the rider applies the front brake near the tire's adhesion limit, the front tire may break loose and skid. Since it is the front tire which establishes and maintains the turn, a front tire skid means the bike stops turning and instead follows a tangent path outward and slides off the road to the outside of the turn. And since the bike is leaned hard left when the turn stops, the bike rolls left and collapses on the pavement in a classic lowside crash.

Comment: Assume wheels aren't going to lock up and skid (yet). Your answer assumes we want to maintain stability. Of course we do, and so need to change steering inputs to stay stable, but what I want to know is what the added forces due to the brake being applied tend to do to the lean angle at that moment, before other inputs are changed. I believe you're saying the bike will lean over more; am I reading that correctly? This disagrees with my gut feeling that the bike will seem to pick itself up in the corner if I brake, and I want to better understand why, either way.

Comment: Understood. to answer your questions requires the input of experts who can deal with the following: a rider "knows" their bike and can solve the turn radius/speed/lean angle/steering input equation in real time, and factor in braking inputs. a skilled rider performs this calculus semi-unconsciously which makes the bike's kinematics and the rider's inputs difficult to separate for analysis. But there is hope: this is a solved problem in the mech eng world; search under "tracking vehicle dynamics" for the key references. good luck! -NN

Comment: I think I could anecdotally solve it to some extent for my own curiosity by getting into a corner in a nice wide open space, taking hands off the handlebars (!), ensuring I'm cornering stably, then gently pressing the back brake and seeing what happens. I'd already be slowing down after taking hands off (I don't have a throttle lock), but I'd at least find out what slowing down *more* does to my lean.

Comment: wear your helmet!!!